# What are the numerical methods for solving matrix differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matrix-equations

Which numerical methods can be used to solve matrix differential equations of the following form?

$$\textbf{X}'(t)=\textbf{A}\textbf{X}(t)+\textbf{B}(t)$$

Do you have book or article suggestions about it?

Comment: So is there an expression dependent on $t$ in each element of $\bf X$ and $'$ means the element wise partial derivative wrt $t$?

Comment: Yes, there is. $'$ means elementwise derivative w.r.t $t$

Comment: Good. It makes the question easier to understand if we know what the notation means.

Comment: You can vectorize $\bf X$ and represent differentiation with a matrix multiplication.

Comment: Could you explain more explicitly?  Sorry, I can' t understand what you say.

Answer (score 1):

I assume $X(t)$ is a matrix.  Let $X_i(t)$ be the $i$th column of $X(t)$ and let $B_i(t)$ be the $i$th column of $B(t)$. The differential equation $X'(t) = A X(t) + B(t)$ is equivalent to the statement that $X_i'(t) = A X_i(t) + B_i(t)$ for all $i$.  You can solve each of these linear systems of ODEs independently using any standard technique.

Answer (score 1):

The $k$-th column of the *linear* matrix differential equation $\rm \dot X = A X + U$ is the differential equation

$$\dot{\mathrm x}_k = \mathrm A \mathrm{x}_k + \mathrm{u}_k$$

whose closed-form solution is

$$\mathrm x_k (t) = \exp (t \mathrm A) \, \mathrm{x}_k (0) + \displaystyle\int_0^t \exp ((t-\tau) \mathrm A) \, \mathrm{u}_k (\tau) \, \mathrm d \tau$$

Thus, the closed-form solution of $\rm \dot X = A X + U$ is

$$\boxed{\mathrm X (t) = \exp (t\mathrm A) \, \mathrm X (0) + \int_0^t \exp ((t-\tau) \mathrm A) \, \mathrm U (\tau) \, \mathrm d \tau }$$

Why use numerical methods?

Comment: Firstly, thanks. I am seeking another method except for the method you used. I am a master student and want to learn different methods (numerical or analytical)

Comment: You could apply a numerical integration scheme to this solution if you do not have access to symbolic software.

Comment: @HD239 Let $h := t_{k+1} - t_k$ be the time step. Hence, $$\mathrm X (t_{k+1}) = \exp (h \mathrm A) \left( \mathrm X (t_k) + \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} \exp (- \tau \mathrm A) \, \mathrm U (\tau) \, \mathrm d \tau \right)$$ If you want, say, 4th order Runge-Kutta, then use the 4th order approximation of the matrix exponentials.

Comment: The reason you wouldn't use this, is because the exponential of a matrix is often too costly to computer let alone integrate. For certain problems it is also very sensitive to computational error

Comment: @KyleW Hence, the 4th order approximation (RK4).